# MessageBox not shown after MFC dialog

Tags: c++, mfc

I have simple MFC application with MFC dialog:

```
BOOL CPreparationApp::InitInstance()

{


    MyDlg Dlg;
    MessageBox(0, L"Text1", L"MessageBox caption", MB_OK);
    m_pMainWnd = &Dlg;
    Dlg.DoModal();
    CString strLine=Dlg.m_editText;

    MessageBox(0, L"Text2", L"MessageBox caption", MB_OK);

        return TRUE;
}
```

Message box with Text1 is shown, but after pressing OK in modal dialog Message box with Text2 is not shown? Why?

Comment: comment Dlg code and see if two message boxes appear (they will) and then try to use modal less dialog because i think its modaling over the second message box

Comment: Try commenting out the assignment `m_pMainWnd = &Dlg`

Comment: After messagebox with text1 MyDlg should open. Are you closing that? After closing that messagebox with text2 should open.

Comment: Another hint: for dialog based apps InitInstance must return FALSE, not TRUE.

Comment: after commenting m_pMainWnd = &Dlg second message box is displayed. But why dialog makes influence on MessageBox? If I debug this application break point on second MessagesBox goes normally.

Comment: Before `DoModal()` returns, the dialog's `HWND` is destroyed, so this leaves `m_pMainWnd` pointing to a `CWnd` object with no `HWND`. I suspect this is messing up the core MFC code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting `m_pMainWnd` to your dialog, you're telling MFC that the program should end when the dialog is closed. Don't do that.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dlg.DoModal();
```

it's called *Modal Window* here. It will not return until you close Dlg. And then, the MessageBox of TEXT2 will show up.

or else, you could write like following to create Dlg as *Non-modal Window* if it is derived from CDialog

```
MyDlg *pDlg = new MyDlg;
pDlg->Create(IDD_MYDLG_DLG, NULL);
pDlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

Oh, i didn't saw it's in CWinApp. It is because after you call DoModal to something referenced by CWinApp::m_pMainWnd, then WM_QUIT message will be added in message queue. And every window created then will be quit. It's about something of how MFC destroy a CWnd. If you want more, please read about MFC source code of following functions.

```
int CWnd::RunModalLoop(DWORD dwFlags)
void CWnd::OnNcDestroy()
void CDialog::EndDialog(int nResult)
```

But if you just want the second box to show, just remove this:

```
m_pMainWnd = &Dlg;
```

Comment: But after pressing OK modal window is closed and I expect second MessageBox.